# Unable to create virtual enviroment for Python 3.8.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

Is there anyway to create virtual envs for python 3.8.10 ?

`python3 -m venv venv`

Returns

```
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt install python3.8-venv
```

`apt-get install python3.8-venv`

Returns

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.8-venv : Depends: python3.8 (= 3.8.5-1~20.04) but 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Do the solutions provided in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285650/cannot-install-python-venv-on-ubuntu-20-04-after-upgrading-from-bionic) help?

Comment: Nope. The only way to install it seems to be downgrading from 3.8.10

Comment: Use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) or something similar instead of messing around your system's Python interpreter

Answer (score 0):

TLDR

- as mentioned by @Maurice use pyenv instead of messing around with the system interpreter.
- Make sure pyenv is not using the systems interpreter `pyenv versions`.
- Make sure to remove any existing venv folder. The surprise
  `venv` folder from step 2 confused me to no end.

Lonng story:

1. Installed pyenv but version still set to point to system.

```
$ pyenv versions

- system (set by .pyenv/version)
```

2. Creating venv with **system Python** failed with the messages shown below. A `venv` folder was created despite the failure!!

```
$ python3 -m venv venv

The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

$ apt-get install python3.8-venv

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.8-venv : Depends: python3.8 (= 3.8.5-1~20.04) but 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

3. Installing and using 3.8.10 pyenv returned a different error

```
$ pyenv install 3.8.10
$ pyenv local 3.8.10
$ pyenv versions

  system 
* 3.8.10 (set by ./.python-version)

$ python3 -m venv venv

Error: Command '['home/project/venv/bin/python', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

4. Removing the `venv` folder created from step 2 and rerunning `python3 -m venv venv` activates it properly.